# Efficient Regex for requiring a specific sentence pattern but allowing html etc

Tags: regex

(As is often the case, while writing this, I *think* I fixed the expression itself so it now works for my purposes, so efficiency is now my main concern - but I would still like input as to whether the expression can be improved or will let through way more than it should, so I have left the entire explanation in.)

I am trying to write a regular expression which will validate that user-submitted text matches a length requirement. Users must write 7 or more full sentences of 4 or more words. We are defining this as follows:

```
- 4 words means 3 or more sections of '1 or more non-space characters followed by 1 or more spaces', then 1 instance of '1 or more non-space characters optionally followed by a space' (because some people like to put spaces before their punctuation marks I guess)  
- A sentence is ended with a punctuation mark (.?!)  
- Zero or more spaces are allowed after each sentence  
- (Repeat 7 times)
```

This definition can be changed to anything sensible, but that's what I came up with so far. Which gives me the following RegEx:

```
((\S+\s+){3,}\S+[.?!]\s*){7,}
```

This seems to work, but I have obviously fudged many things and wonder if anyone has a better idea. (It has to allow for html at any point, and a lot of other quirks from users' writing. I am not too concerned about people gaming the system - there are still manual checks, this is just a first-stage check to lighten the load.)

My other main concern is efficiency - I'm new to regex and don't know what is a 'normal' calculation time, but the debugger(s) I'm using are struggling at times when I paste in a block of text to check, and I don't know if this is caused by my RegEx or the debugger. It is often timing out on longer sections of text where there is no match. Is there a more efficient way to do what I'm wanting...?

Comment: I think it'd be more efficient to just parse through the input text searching for word tokens and punctuations and keeping necessary counters than just using regex. It seems like regex would be too much. What language are you using?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using regex for this? It's not the best solution for this problem.

Comment: regex parsers are implemented differently in different programming languages (which also means that they have different flavors), some of them are very efficient, some are not.

Comment: Note that `\s` is the character set for all whitespace characters, not just space. If you only want to match space, you should just use ` ` (a literal space).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know a huge amount about the system being used as I'm helping a friend (who also doesn't know very much) and don't have access to it myself (useless, I know). Basically the system presents us with a box and says 'you can put some RegEx here if you want', and that's the only validation option apart from a maximum length or field type. Hence using RegEx.

Comment: It's a forum system that uses MyBB, if anyone is familiar with that - that's about all I know. Data is stored in SQL tables and it accepts PHP in other parts of the system.

Comment: Sounds like there's not much you can do to improve it then, after all - you don't have access to the system. As for the regex, I find it hard to believe that anyone can come up with a different equivalent regex which will perform better in orders of magnitude (meaning: anything noticeable by the user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when doing full text match, always surround the regex with `^...$`. `^` anchors the start of the regex to the start of the validation string, and `$` anchors the end of the regex to the end of the string. Otherwise, if it fails to match, it will repeat the validation attempt starting on every single character (Which, at minimum (4 words * 3 spaces) * 7 sentences = excessive amount of work).

Second, always use mutually exclusive groups where you can. `\S (anything not white-space)` includes the characters `.?!`, So on failing to find punctuation, it has to backtrack and retry each `\S` it matched. (Namely, because the first pass would mark it as a word instead of punctuation) So I would recommend replace `\S` with a more mutually exclusive "anything not white-space or punctuation" `[^\s.?!]`. Note that that [] contains a lowercase s instead of an uppercase one. `[^...]` is "match any character NOT in this group".

Those 2 things will drop you from catastrophic backtracking to a reasonable ~1-3k steps depending on paragraph length.

UPDATE:
If you would allow a small alteration to the validation logic, making it so that multiple short sentences can count together as one sentence, then the following regex should do.

```
^(\s*(\S+\s+){3}([.?!]\s*)?([^\s.?!]+\s+)*\S+\s*[.?!]){7,}$
```

This hybrid version will allow short sentences without causing catastrophic backtracking. Without the small rule change, you will need to nest a variable length pattern inside a variable length pattern; which is catastrophic when the pattern isn't fully mutually exclusive. (updated demo)

Also, technically you can replace `{7,}$` with just `{7}` if once 7 sentences have been found, you don't care what comes after that. (That will let the regex stop as soon as minimal viability is found, which would be more accepting of some extreme edge cases)

(You can play with it [here](https://regex101.com/r/lTj70P/3) on regex101.com)

Comment: (regex101 happens to be the one I'm using - my fave debugger so far). I will try out the anchoring, though I'm somewhat trying to get my head around whether I definitely want both anchors - I'm a bit concerned about it erroneously failing certain things? I will test and see, however.  And for the replacement - thing is, I want it to accept, say, 8 sentences where one of the middle sentences only has 3 words - surely that would make that fail because it comes across an end-of-sentence that doesn't meet the 4 word req?

Comment: When I add the anchors, it gives me catastrophic backtracking... but without them, it accepts the text I'm using. So I think the anchors would be a problem for what I want to check, but also this says to me that any very long piece of text that the system would normally reject, is going to cause catastrophic backtracking because it hasn't found a match fast enough... sounds bad? Is there a standard way that a system would deal with something like that - will it most likely just time out and reject? (I don't want to risk gumming up the whole darn site, as it isn't mine...)

Comment: @RosieThomas Updated answer with a hybrid solution. As for the fail part, since regex is more like a specification, how the engine is implemented (the regex flavor) and how the code calling that regex is written, this can range anywhere from "regex failed" to "thread crashed from exception". I would recommend testing your system against something stupid like `((((((((((((((((((\S+)*\S*)*\S)*\S)*\S)*\S)*\S)*\S)*\S)*)*\S*)*\S)*\S)*\S)*\S)*\S)*\S)*\S)*`. Ideally, this should just fail, and if it causes any serious problems, you might want another solution or use a different site.

Comment: Updated answer solved it (though for my purposes the `{7}` at the end seems to be the correct option, and not `{7,}$` as I had it before). I'm still testing to double check, but the things that caused major problems before are now working nicely so I foresee a positive outcome. Thank you very much, extremely helpful! :)